# TV episode about patient who has revenge on plastic surgeon who botched his/her surgery

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, horror

I'm not sure if this was an episode of "*Tales from the Dark Side*" or "*Twilight Zone*" or something else from the 90s (or late 80s). The plot was a patient (transgender?) wanted to have surgery to make her look beautiful. However, as the plastic surgeon got drunk the night before the operation, his hands were shaky and the patient got disfigured.

The patient decided to get revenge though. With skillful make-up, she seduces the doctor in a bar. Once they get up a room, she removes the make-up revealing her disfigured face then slashes the doctor's face with a knife or scalpel. I remember there was then a voice-over.

Does it ring a bell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that does ring a bell.  There were a number of pretty good series that basically emulated the Twilight Zone in format and style.

One of those was the HBO-created series called [The Hitchhiker (IMDB)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085031/)

The specific episode you are referring to is called "Face To Face" -

> Homely and desperate transsexual Nina Russell hires prominent, but sleazy and arrogant plastic surgeon Dr. Christopher Hamilton to create a more alluring and attractive face for her....

[IMDB: The Hitchhiker - episodes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085031/episodes)

I remember Robert Vaughan (aka Napoleon Solo on the Man From U.N.C.L.E. series) as the surgeon, who was either still high/drunk or very strung out from partying when he botched the surgery.

Comment: Wonderful! Finally a name to attach to the memory. Didn't even know about the series "The Hitchhiker", as I just assumed it was either Twilight Zone or Tales from the Dark Side. A quick search shows Youtube even has the episode. Thanks!

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII - the main attraction for that series (hey, I was a teenager when it came out) was that, since it was made for HBO, they tended to push their content to reflect that they could do "R"-rated takes on Twilight Zone-type themes.

Comment: The nice thing with the Internet is you can research your childhood memories. After watching the youtube video (which showed some surprises that I didn't remember, like the plane in the end), it turns out the patient was played by a pretty actress named Sonja Smits.